How to know when a gnuradio File Source has finished reading?
I am writing a python program based on gnuradio, and using a gnuradio File Source. I cant seem to find a way to do that...
I tried looking at the documentation for this block, but i couldn't find anything useful. I also tried calling the work function of the block using python, but it didn't work (I couldn't provide the correct parameter types that gnuradio was expecting).
I am looking for something like:
if (file_source_name.items_remaining() == 0):
print("done.")

That's not a problem your block needs to solve. It also can't know, by design.
Your block simply gets called until all output of the file source has been consumed.

The reason I want to access such information, is because I have the file source block in a flow graph, as a part of a larger project. I want to be able to notify the user of the project when this certain flow graph is done

you'd do that by starting the flow graph, and then calling top_block.wait(). Once that returns, your flow graph is done.

Thank you! I can't believe I didn't think of that, it was in plain sight :D, is there a way to do that without having to wait? (So that I can activate multiple of these flow graphs at the same time?

If you start multiple at the same time, are you sure you don't just want one top_block with multiple distinct flow graphs inside? Other than that: sleeping threads are cheap, just call tb.run() each in its own thread of a thread group, and in your main thread, wait for all of them to join
